# fetch (or AJAX Get) returns html but Postman returns xml from feedburner

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, rss, podcast

I'm trying to retrieve an xml podcast feed in my application. I'm having a problem where one of the `fetch` requests I'm making returns an html document instead of the xml feed. The weird part is if I send a `/GET` to the same url with Postman, it returns me the rss feed. It also appears to work with the code snippet here on SO (example below).

An example of it returning a html document can be seen at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wz4nps83/2/), which has the exact same code as the snippet below.

Is anyone able to help me understand why this is happening please? I feed like it could be resolved by setting some sort of request header, maybe?

**Update**
Weirdly, it seems like the linked fiddle sometimes fetches the xml; I think because it caches the calls. If you open it in a new incognito window, it fetches the html again.

```js
$('#fetchXML').click(function(){
   $('#xmlContent').text('Loading ...');

 const feedUrl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://feeds.wnyc.org/dearhankandjohn';
  const headers = new Headers({
   'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'
  });
  
  
  fetch(feedUrl, headers)
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
  })
  .then(function(xmlText) {
   $('#xmlContent').text(xmlText);
  })
  .catch(function(err){
   $('#xmlContent').text(err);
  });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td><button id="fetchXML">
  Fetch Feed
  </button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="xmlContent"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I am getting the RSS feed even in JSFiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/wz4nps83/2/) you mentioned.

Comment: @VardamanPK I've added an update. Seems to be cache thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Pass the `format` as a parameter in the URL.

`https://feeds.feedburner.com/codinghorror?format=html`

---

Feedburner returns raw XML by default:

```sh
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43,39"
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
```

But it also sends a stylesheet so the browser can apply style the markup (view source).

Time ago, the deprecated, `fmt` parameter was used, now the with `format` you can ask either for `html` or `xml`.

`https://feeds.feedburner.com/codinghorror?format=html`

```sh
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43,39"
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I was finally able to fix this by setting the `ReferrerPolicy` to `no-referrer` in the `fetch()` call. I am not 100% certain why this works other than that this is a feeburner specific thing where they've got a conditional return policy based on the referrer type.